# Is Redisson thread-safe itself?

Tags: java, redis, concurrency, thread-safety, redisson

Redisson client is said to be thread-safe.
My question is, if Redisson and its object instances are thread-safe, what is the use of Locks like RLock?
Does that enhance performance on multi-instance multi-concurrency environments? or Redisson is thread-safe by letting users use those Locks instead of being thread-safe itself?